# databricks python pyspark method format_number does not exist

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to create a function in databricks python that changes a number like 3.750000 to 3.75.  basically removing trailing zeroes.  I found this method in pyspark but it doesn't seem to be working.  does anyone know the issue?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import format_number
a = 3.7500
format_number(str(a),'0.##')
```

here is error

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method format_number([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
```